# Custom validation in woo-commerce adding post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress hook as below

```
function modify_post_title( $data , $postarr )
{   
 $error = 0;
 if(SomeVlidation == false) {
     $error = 1;
  }
  return $error;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 2 );
```

as i made validation some conditions in my hook now what i want is that  `wp_insert_post_data` should not execute if my hook (modify_post_title) return $error = 1;

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? What is your end goal? There may be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot halt hook execution because action hooks don't check for return values from the callback function. The only option is to use `wp_die` or `exit`

```
function modify_post_title( $data , $postarr )
{   
 $error = 0;
 if(SomeVlidation == false) {
     $error = 1;
     wp_die("<p>Ok we are terminating here!!</p>");
  }
  return $error;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 2 );
```